# Search file upward in parent dir and open in vsplit or newtab

Tags: vim

I want to open a bld.log file as default else the input filename in vim vsplit window or in newtab no matter from which nested subfolder I am opening it.
So I added following function in ~/.vimrc but instead of opening searched path path1 its opening the newfile with name path1.
Please let me know what I am missing here or how can I achieve it ?

```
function! Err1(...)  
if a:0 > 0
    let s:path1 = findfile(a:1,';')
else
    let s:path1 = findfile('bld.log',';')
end
exec ':vsp ' . s:path1
endfunction  
command -nargs=1 Err call Err1(...)
```

P.S. I want to do above in .vimrc only not in .bashrc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this using `exec` (this answers the original question before edit, how to use `:tabnew` from the function):

```
function! Err1()
    let s:path1 = findfile('README.md','.,**')
    echo findfile('README.md',';')
    exec ':tabnew ' . s:path1
endfunction
command Err call Err1()
```

Here is an example of function which accepts an optional parameter:

```
function! Err1(...)
    if len(a:1) > 0
      let l:path = a:1
    else
      let l:path = 'README.md'
    end
    let l:file = findfile(l:path,'.,**')
    if len(l:file) > 0
      exec ':vsp ' . l:file
    else
      echom 'File not found: ' . l:path . ' ' . l:file
    end
endfunction
command -nargs=* Err call Err1('<args>')
```

Another option is to add `set path=.,**` into the .vimrc and then just use the standard "file" command, like `:find bld.log`.

Comment: Thanks a lot Boris. Also one more doubt can you tell me same function can we rewrite to receive README.md as argument i.e runtime parameter.

Comment: @sidyll : I tried this but not working     `function! Err1(file1)
        let s:path1 = findfile('a:file1',';')  
    "findfile('xr_bld.ncs4k.log',';')  
        exec ':vsp ' . s:path1  
    endfunction  
command Err call Err1()`

Comment: @ypp if you're using a variable as parameters, remove the quotes `findfile(a:file, ...`

Comment: @ypp you edited the question and my answer now looks like a useless one, because you already have the `exec` in your code. When you have the question answered - just mark it as "accepted" and if you have more questions - ask in comments or post another separate question. It is really annoying to see when the question turns into something completely different after you answered it. I also added information about `:find` command into my answer, check maybe you can just use the standard feature instead of making your own command.

Comment: @Boris I am Sorry if you feel offended, but i wasn't able to add code in comment So I edited original question. My mistake I apologize.

Comment: @ypp I don't feel offended, everything's alright. Just the question editing is to improve the question, add examples, more info, etc. It really breaks the SO format when you edit the question and replace it with new one. I also added an example of function with parameters to my answer.

Comment: Any particular reason for using `findfile()` twice instead of the `s:path1` variable in the first code block?

Comment: @JairLopez no, it is copied from the [original question](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/36022615/1). I think the intention was to check what findfile() actually returns.

Comment: @Boris Serebrov I tried with your updated answer. I think instead of  `exec ':vsp ' . l:path` you meant as `    exec ':vsp ' . l:file`. with this the default is working and opening README.md but if I pass argument as filename then it vsplitting itself i.e .vimrc and not opening the file in argument.

Comment: @Boris Serebrov with latest updated answer opening README.md if we not pass any args is working but if I pass argument as filename then it vsplitting itself (i.e .vimrc) instead of opening the file in argument

Comment: @ypp check the updated version with fixes, I also added a handling for a "file not found" situation.

Comment: @Boris Serebrov I just changed `let l:file = findfile(l:path,'.,**')` to let l:file = findfile(l:path,';.,**') and it's working with all the cases. If I not add the ';' in '.,**' then it always say README.md not found. Also If I enter filename with whitespace at end as argument then then it say file not found. Thanks for your help.